How to quickly pull information from an online database that has a server limit per call?
So there is this online database with more than a million entries. I need to retrieve all of them at once to add them to a specific part of my website (I am using javascript/typescript btw). The problem is that this database has a server limit of 2000 entries output per call. This is not my database so I have no control over this number, and I have contacted the people responsible for it and they have no intention of changing this limit. The database is a OWS url of geographic data in GeoJSON format
So far the only option I have come up with is sending 500 requests to the database of 2000 entries each in a loop, and I have tried using promises to make that process faster. This has worked in the general sense but it takes hours, like I left my computer sending requests the entire night, and had to kill it in the morning at about half the requests made. This is not feasible for me. Does anyone have any idea how to make this faster, is there something wrong that I am doing or another way of pulling this information?
Here is my code for reference: (I have omitted the database url for privacy reasons)
export const fetchData = async (url: string) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/geo+json'
            }
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data. Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const fetchIteratively = async (url: string, iterations: number, interval: number = 2000, startIndex: number = 0) => {
    const promises: Promise<any>[] = []

    for (let i = 0; i < (interval * iterations); i += interval) {
        promises.push(fetchData(url + `&maxFeatures=${interval}&startIndex=${i}`))
    }

    try {
        const allJSONs = await Promise.all(promises);
        const combined = mergeGeoJSONs(allJSONs.flatMap(file => file.features));
        return combined;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during concurrent fetching:', error);
        throw error; // Rethrow the error
    }
}


do you need to pull this data on a schedule? If so, is there a "delta" endpoint giving you only the updated entries, or a way to sort by last modified and only pull those in. You'd still have to import them once though.

I would suggest asking the actual problem you're trying to solve with this, not asking how to achieve your own proposed solution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The chances are whatever you're trying to display to a user doesn't require you to pull down a million objects from an API, and any answer you get will probably not be the optimum solution to your actual problem.

Thank you for the help! That makes perfect sense. I will ask the issue by itself, perhaps the solution does not require pulling that much data at all.
